two HTTPS applications on the same host
Sorry, if there is some similar question.
I'm interesting if it possible to run to HTTPS applications on the same host machine, for example:

Python FastAPI Back-End on port **8000 ** that use HTTPS
JS React Front-End on port **4000 ** that also use HTTPS

It will work fine without any tricks like TLS Proxy? or so on?
I have read that one host can have only one certificate what is mean only one application can have HTTPS, but beside that I read that it is possible to do it without any Proxy, nginx and so...
I would be so thankful if someone could explain me that part, or give some links for resources

This is not programming or development and is offtopic, but any source that says a 'host' can only have one cert or one domain is at least 15 years out of date and should not be used for any purpose. You can have: different server processes (e.g. your python and nodejs) with different certs, or one server process with different certs, on different ports since the very beginning; on one server process and port different certs for different domain names IF both your server and the client(s) use SNI -- Server Name Indication -- which practically all do since about 2010; ...

... or on one server process and port multiple domain names using a single multidomain or wildcard cert since about 2000. But "just link" answers are also against policy even if the question was ontopic. Please see the 'help center' at the question mark in the nav bar at the top, or here

Why shouldn't two services on the same host be able to use the same certificate? You just need to configure them properly and provide the certificate + private key in the format each server prefers.
